# Menu usando Css Grid

Tags: html5, css3

Estou iniciando meus estudos com CSS Grid e para treinar estou tentando fazer um menu simples, a estrutura do meu grid tem **4 colunas** por **4 linhas**, assim como definido no código.

Eu estou tentando fazer o menu usando uma lista porem eu não faço a minima ideia de como posicionar esses elementos na minha grid, como eu vou posicioná-los de forma linear sendo que eu possuo 4 colunas e 4 linhas ?

Devo posicionar cada elemento em uma coluna ?

Posso posicionar todos os elementos mesmo o site tendo 4 colunas ?

Abaixo segue o meu código do que eu tentei fazer, porem não deu certo, se puderem me dar uma direção eu agradeço e muito !!!

index.html

```
<body>
   <div class="container">

    <div class="item1">
        <ul class="texto">
            <li>Inicio</li>
            <li>Sobre</li>
            <li>Github</li>
            <li>Linkedin</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">Header</div>
    <div class="item3">Conteudo</div>
    <div class="item4">Footer</div>

    </div>
 </body>
```

main.css

```css
* {margin: 0px;}

.item1 {grid-area: menu;}

.item2 { grid-area: cabecalho;}

.item3 {grid-area: conteudo;}

.item4 {grid-area: rodape;}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 200px 400px 200px;
    grid-template-areas: 'menu menu menu menu'
                     'cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho'
                     'conteudo conteudo conteudo conteudo'
                     'rodape rodape rodape rodape';
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 10px;
    }

.container > div {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    }
```

conteudo.css

```css
ul {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente seu problema é que vc colocou o `display:inline` na `UL` e deveria ser na `LI`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se vc quer que cada item LI da sua UL fique dentro de uma coluna do Grid vc vai ter que fazer um `Sub-Grid`, que na verdade é um Grid dentro de outro... já que o `Sub-Grid` ainda não foi oficializado pela W3C. Para isso coloque `disply:grid` tb na `UL` e faça a divisão em 4 colunas como fez no Grid principal

Aqui tem um artigo sobre o Sub-Grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid não recomendo que leia até entender bem o funcionamento do Grid normal rss, mas basicamente é reaproveitar no Filho o Grid do Pai, mas atualmente não é possível, vc tem que refazer o Grid no Filho como falei...

**Veja o código da imagem acima**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: cabecalho;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: conteudo;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: rodape;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 200px 400px 200px;
  grid-template-areas: 'menu menu menu menu'
    'cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho'
    'conteudo conteudo conteudo conteudo'
    'rodape rodape rodape rodape';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}


ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item1">
    <ul class="texto">
      <li>Inicio</li>
      <li>Sobre</li>
      <li>Github</li>
      <li>Linkedin</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">Header</div>
  <div class="item3">Conteudo</div>
  <div class="item4">Footer</div>

</div>
```

---

**EDIT - Alternativa Grid / Sub-Grid**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo acima eu dividi a UL em 4, de forma que cada coluna dela ficasse igual a divisão feita no container Pai. para isso eu usei `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: cabecalho;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: conteudo;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: rodape;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 200px 400px 200px;
  grid-template-areas: 'menu menu menu menu'
    'cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho'
    'conteudo conteudo conteudo conteudo'
    'rodape rodape rodape rodape';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}


ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item1">
    <ul class="texto">
      <li>Inicio</li>
      <li>Sobre</li>
      <li>Github</li>
      <li>Linkedin</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">Header</div>
  <div class="item3">Conteudo</div>
  <div class="item4">Footer</div>

</div>
```

---

**EDIT - Alternativa Grid + Flex**

Como vc quer o menu na horizontal, usar um *Container* Flex Dentro de um *Grid Track* pode ser a solução perfeita. Mas para equalizar os itens internos vc precisa colocar `flex:1;` nas `LI`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta que vc coloque na sua `UL` as propriedades  `display: flex;` e `justify-content: space-around;` para distribuir os itens como na imagem acima

Veja o código abaixo

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: cabecalho;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: conteudo;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: rodape;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 200px 400px 200px;
  grid-template-areas: 'menu menu menu menu'
    'cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho cabecalho'
    'conteudo conteudo conteudo conteudo'
    'rodape rodape rodape rodape';

  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}


ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item1">
    <ul class="texto">
      <li>Inicio</li>
      <li>Sobre</li>
      <li>Github</li>
      <li>Linkedin</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">Header</div>
  <div class="item3">Conteudo</div>
  <div class="item4">Footer</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu perguntei se era possível colocar cara palavra em uma coluna diferente pq pensei q essa fosse a maneira correta de se fazer mas como vi n parece muito produtivo kkk, mais uma pergunta eu poderia usar flex-box para "ajeitar" os elementos em cada coluna ou nao ficaria "correto" de se fazer ? pq n tenho experiencia de mercado então gostaria de fazer algo semelhante a realidade, Obrigado !

Comment: @GiovanniManganotti sim essa é uma ótima oportunidade para unir Grid + Flex, veja o **EDIT** que eu fiz no final da resposta incluindo essa opção de usar Flex para distribuir os  itens do Menu

Comment: humm acabei de ver, entendi como funciona, agora ficou um pouco mais claro essa ideia de usar flex-box junto com css grid, Obrigado pela ajuda !!!

Comment: @GiovanniManganotti se te interessar fiz uma nova edição na resposta, corrigi uma config do Felx na LI para ficar mais alinhado com o Grid de olunas do Pai, e tb fiz um código novo dessa vez usando um Sub-Grid, colocando Display:Grid na UL também para alinhas as LI direitinho